# How to unsubscribe behaviour subject in angular8

Tags: angular, behaviorsubject, replaysubject

Hi i am using Angular8 application, in which i have used Replay subject and Behaviour subject, for the initial click it hits the api for only 1 time, but if i change between tabs, the subscription hits fr multiple times, if i have clicked tab for 3 times, the API gets hitted for 6 times, so it starts multiplying, is there any way to unsubscribe the behavious subject, i want the API to hit only one time, i tried with unsubscribing, but it didnt work.

TS:
**App.component.ts:**

```
_otherTab: ReplaySubject<any> = new ReplaySubject();

  other() {
      this.othertab = 2;
      this._otherTab.next(2); 
  }
```

**HTML:**

```
  <div class="card-header bg-dark border-bottom-0">
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-fill card-header-tabs" id="" role="tablist">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#basic" role="tab">User</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item" (click)="other()">
                            <a data-toggle="tab" href="#eo" role="tab" 
                            [ngClass]=" {'nav-link':(true),'disabled' : (_otherTabEnabled === false) }" >Other</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

  <div class="tab-pane" id="eo" role="tabpanel">
   <app-other-table [othertab]="_otherTab"></app-other-table>
   </div>
```

**Other Component:**

```
 @Input() othertab: BehaviorSubject<any>;
     ngOnInit() {
        this.othertab.subscribe(val => {
          if (val) {
            this.showTab = true;
          }
        });
      }
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-ck3u8u-go2ond?file=src%2Fapp%2Fother-table%2Fother-table.component.ts)

Comment: I have gone through you demo and I am unable to see any memory leaks even if I visit other tab and back to the main tab.

Comment: but in my application it is hitting multiple times same APi which is inside ngonInit

Answer (score 0):

in your Other component, where you subscribe, you *must* remember to unsubscribe. Otherwise you can have memory leak issues etc.

So where you have the subscribe, remember to unsubscribe.

```
 subs;
 @Input() othertab: BehaviorSubject<any>;

     ngOnInit() {
        this.subs = this.othertab.subscribe(val => {
          if (val) {
            this.showTab = true;
          }
        });
      }

    ngOnDestroy(){
        this.subs.unsubscribe();
    }
```

Comment: what exactly is the api that is getting hit multiple times? I have run your code and have been unable to discern this

Comment: in my application, if i click other tab for first time, this subscribe will hit one time, if i change tab and come to same tab, then the val will be hitting multiple times

Comment: so the API inisde ngOnit will hit multiple times

Comment: using the following stackblitz, forked from yours, I logged the different situations (ngOnInit, subscribe, etc) and they are not called more than once. If there are not the right places, please point me in the direction of the right ones
https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-ck3u8u-f6gr5w?file=src%2Fapp%2Fother-table%2Fother-table.component.ts

Comment: ya with Demo i created it is hitting only one, but in my application that is hitting multiple times, let me create new demo and try to reproduce issue what i am facing in my actual application

Comment: i am not able to reproduce same issue here, but in my application it is triggering multiple times

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-ck3u8u-wrnsis?file=src%2Fapp%2Fother-table%2Fother-table.component.ts my code is something like this in my application

Comment: the new stackblitz has many many errors... check the console

Comment: ya but that is similar to my application code,but in stackblitz its showing error